# Google app invite tracking if you already have custom dimensions

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-app-invites

I would like to track Google app invites in Google Analytics. There is a guide how to set it up. One of the steps is the create a custom dimension. However it says:

> Note that this dimension must be at Index 1 in the table of Custom Demensions

Our GA property already has custom dimensions. So index 1 is already taken by another custom dimension.

How can we use a custom dimension that's not at index 1? Or how can we change the index of existing dimensions? Or how can we delete an existing dimension?